# Why do the German Visa appointment at Bangalore Consulate get deleted

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas, applications

I had an appointment in Nov, I went with all my documents to the German consulate Bangalore but my name was not there in their list and was not allowed for the interview. I could find that this happened to many people in the recent past. First of all its very difficult to get a slot and that too if getting deleted what could be done. Again getting a new slot is such a herculian task that everything looks so uncertain. How does this deletion take place, who does this?

Comment: This sounds like it must have been a very frustrating experience for you. Unfortunately I don't believe anybody here (or anywhere, except for the consulate itself) will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to deal with such a problem is to send them a letter informing them of this situation togeather with a printout of the agreed appointment.

Only with specific samples will it be possible to determine

- that the agreed appointment had been deleted afterwards
- by whom and if it was justified